# Which three telescopes are these atop a mountain in Hawaii as seen on CNN? Is this webcam view available to the public?

Tags: identify-this-object, observatory

CNN's new video [Alaska reached temperatures warmer than California in December](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TSeGZKDbXHA) includes file footage from a webcam from the top of a mountain in Hawaii showing three observatories.

Annotation at the top says

> CFHT/December 3, Waimea, Hawaii

and embedded digital data at the bottom says

> Catwalk PTZ: (plus date and time)

**Question:** Is it possible to identify which three telescopes these are? Is this webcam view available to the public?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These appear to be (from left to right, or near to far):

- [Gemini North Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemini_Observatory)
- [University of Hawaii 2.2-meter telescope](https://www.ifa.hawaii.edu/88inch/)
- [United Kingdom Infrared Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_Infrared_Telescope)

For an arial view see [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@19.823014,-155.4695698,258m/data=!3m1!1e3).

The webcam appears to be on the [Canada France Hawaii Telescope](https://www.cfht.hawaii.edu).  The link to the webcam I think is the appropriate one: [South Webcam](https://www.cfht.hawaii.edu/en/gallery/webcams.php?cam=gemdome).  Note the same "Catwalk PTZ" at the bottom of the image.

[image: PFHT South Webcam Image from 31 December 2021]

Comment: I've never looked up there via google maps, geez there are a lot of telescopes!

Comment: Canada France Hawaii telescope I think.

Comment: @uhoh you want to know what exactly is that telescope in that frame ? And yes CFHT means Canada France Hawaii Telescope

Comment: CFHT isn't in the picture.  The webcam is on CFHT I think.  I also think I found the webcam link.  I will edit the answer.